# how to convert an integer number to decimal kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, split

I am trying to convert cm to ft. I get cm in my convertion function and translate cm to ft. like this

```
val ftHeight = _height * 0.032808399
```

it works properly but `ftHeight` contains ft and inc together. I have to seperate ft and inc values because I show different textfields them.

I seperate `ftHeight` like this

```
val inc = ftHeight.toString().substringAfter(".")
val ft = ftHeight.toString().substringBefore(".")
```

but there is a problem for example I assume that `ftHeight` is equal 3.289812

so that

**ft : 3**

**inc : 289812**

when I try to calculate ft to cm I need to ft and inc values but the value of inc should not be like this

it should be like this for my calculatin

**0.289812**

How can I solve that issue? can you help me ?

hear is my calculation function

```
fun onCmToFtChange(_height: Int) {

        val ftHeight = _height * 0.032808399

        val inc = ftHeight.toString().substringAfter(".")
        val ft = ftHeight.toString().substringBefore(".")

        _viewState.update {
            it.copy(
                ft = ft,
                inc = "${inc[0]}",
                _ft = ft.toInt(),
                _inc = "0.{$inc}".toInt(). // this is incorrect code I just tryed something for this issue but it didnt work
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the way you calculate inc,
Instead of

```
val inc = ftHeight.toString().substringAfter(".")
val ft = ftHeight.toString().substringBefore(".")
```

You can use:

```
val ft = ftHeight.toString().substringBefore(".")
val inc = ftHeight - ft.toInt()
```

**If you want to stick to your previous approach and convert string to Double, you can use:**

```
val inc = ftHeight.toString().substringAfter(".")
val ft = ftHeight.toString().substringBefore(".")
val _inc = "0.$inc".toDouble()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
val ft= ftHeight.toInt()
val inc = ((ftHeight % 1) * 12).toInt()
```

To get the feet and inches. Note I already did the conversion to take into account that a foot is 12 inches